# CakePHP 3 node js controller

Tags: node.js, cakephp-3.0

i created a real time chat trought cakephp 3 with node js

but, from the client, the sender need to refresh the page to see the message

and not the receiver who has the chat updated without reload

currently my client.js look like this

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8082'); //create connection

        $('#form_message').submit(function () {

            var message = $('#message').val();

            var avatar = $('#avatar').val(); // champs caché contenant l'avatar

            socket.emit('message', {message: message, avatar: avatar}); // Transmet le message aux autres


        });
        // message envoyé
         socket.on('message', function(data) {

             $('#list_conv').prepend('<div class="messagemoi"><img src="' + data.avatar + '"alt="image utilisateur" class="img-thumbail"/><p>' + data.message +'</p><span class="date_message">' + data.date + '</span></div>');

        })

         // retour du server
           socket.on('messagerepondu', function(data) {

             $('#list_conv').prepend('<div class="messagemoi other"><img src="' + data.avatar + '"alt="image utilisateur" class="img-thumbail right"/><p>' + data.message +'</p><span class="date_message">' + data.date + '</span></div>');

        })
```

My Controller look like this

```
 public function add() 
{

        $data = array(
        'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('username'), // expediteur
        'destinataire' => $this->request->data['destinataire'],
        'message' =>  $this->linkify_tweet($this->request->data['message']), // message
        'conv' => $conversation,
        //evenement abonnement
        'nom_session' => $this->Auth->user('username'),//nom de session
        'avatar_session' => $this->Auth->user('avatarprofil'),
         'new_conv' => $new_conv
        );

        $message = $this->Messagerie->patchEntity($message, $data);

        if ($this->Messagerie->save($message)) 
        {
            if($this->testnotifmessage($this->request->data['destinataire']) == "oui")
            {
                //évènenement

             $event = new Event('Model.Messagerie.afterAdd', $this, ['message' => $message]);
            $this->eventManager()->dispatch($event);
        }
            // fin évènement


        }
        else
        {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Message non envoyé.'));
        }

       //return $this->redirect('http://localhost/instatux/conversation-1768986576');

}
}
```

how can i put the message inside the sender div , insert the message in the database throught cakephp controller without reload ?

Comment: solved thanks everyone

Comment: You should update your posting with how you solved it, this helps other people who might have the same question. Did you end up using push notifications or something? Anyways update your question with the answer.